# Update part of cache using spring.net in repository possible?

Tags: c#, spring.net

I'm building a repository with caching using spring.net. Can I update/add/delete one item in the cached list without having to rebuild the whole list?

Looking at the documentation and the example project from their site they always clear the cache whenever they update/add/delete one item. Therefore as long as you only read an object or the list of objects the caching works well but it feels stupid having to rebuild the whole cache just because I change one item?

Example:

```
// Cache per item and a list of items
[CacheResult("DefaultCache", "'AllMovies'", TimeToLive = "2m")]
[CacheResultItems("DefaultCache", "'Movie-' + ID")]
public IEnumerable<Movie> FindAll()
{
    return movies.Values;
}

// Update or add an item invalidating the list of objects
[InvalidateCache("DefaultCache", Keys = "'AllMovies'")]
public void Save([CacheParameter("DefaultCache", "'Movie-' + ID")]Movie movie)
{
    if (this.movies.ContainsKey(movie.ID))
    {
        this.movies[movie.ID] = movie;
    }
    else
    {
        this.movies.Add(movie.ID, movie);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having mutable things stored in the cache seems to me a fountain of horrible side effects. Imho that is what you would need if you want to add/remove entries from a cached list.

The implementation of `CacheResultAdvice` and `InvalidateCacheAdvice` allows to store and invalidate an `object` (key) -> `object` (value) combination. You could add another layer and retrieve movie per movie but I think that it is just a case of premature optimization (with the opposite effect).

[CacheResultAdvice](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-net/src/Spring/Spring.Aop/Aspects/Cache/CacheResultAdvice.cs)

[InvalidateCacheAdvice](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-net/src/Spring/Spring.Aop/Aspects/Cache/InvalidateCacheAdvice.cs)

Edit:
Btw. if you use a mature ORM look for integrated level2 caching, if you want to avoid hitting the db server: http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/using-syscache-as-secondary-cache-in-nhibernate

Comment: Thank you! After some time I got back to this and even if I'm a little confused I accept the solution. I just wish the someone would extend the documentation on the spring.net cache. :)